# App eliminada de play store PhoneGap permisos plugin contactos

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

Hola mi app en Play Store a sido eliminada, esto por usar el plugin Contactos en phonegap, debido a que este cuenta con el permiso de acceso a llamadas del celular.

La funcionalidad de mi app es usar los contactos telefonicos, algun alternativa para este plugin o como puedo editarlo para solo tener acceso a la agenda telefónica y no me genere este inconveniente de eliminación de play store con su nueva política de seguridad

los plugins Usados :

1. [plugin-contacts](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-contacts/)
2. [ContactsPhoneNumbers](https://github.com/dbaq/cordova-plugin-contacts-phone-numbers)

el plugin funciona bien pero da permisos extras de llamadas por lo cual bloquean el app

Comment: Porque no simplemente usas lo que android te permite, por ejemplo, tal vez esto te sirva: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider?hl=es-419

Comment: Amigo pues es que estoy utilizando phongap y quisiera saber alguna alternativa o unvplugin especifico gracoas

Comment: Perdón no me fijé bien en la etiqueta